# Screen width and element width don't align when inspecting element?

Tags: html, css, width, inspect

I was resizing a page and observing elements with the inspect element tool and noticed that when my screen is shown to be 599px wide (shown on the top right of the page) that an image extended to be the full width of the screen is apparently only 580px wide.

What accounts for those missing 19 pixels? Which width is correct? I would assume it is the width displayed in the top right hand side since my css breakpoints triggered when I bumped width up by 1 px, but I'm confused about this discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing 19 pixels from the value because of the scrollbar to the right. Devtools displays the actual dimensions of the entire page, while highlighting an element will only give the dimensions of that element, which automatically accounts for the scrollbar when calculating its own width.